# How do I use railties to install files other than migrations (for e.g. config files)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-plugins, rails-engines

I'm using Rails 3.1 and I am able to use railties to install migrations (by doing rake railties:install:migrations FROM=plugin_name). However, I have a couple of config files (.yml, etc.) that I need to copy over as well. 
How do I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

For example see the code in a gem i created: https://github.com/nathanvda/on_the_spot/blob/master/lib/generators/on_the_spot/install/install_generator.rb

Simply put: use [thor](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2009/07/creating-your-own-generators-with-thor/) commands, like `copy_file`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: how do you invoke this particular task. I know that I can run the entire set of operations by running something like "ruby script/rails g import_products:install". But how do I run ONLY a single task, like "copy_javascripts" ?

Comment: To my knowledge the only solution to that is to create different generators.